# How can I set information on a cell in a datagrid based on its header or column?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 DataGrid, like so:

```
<asp:DataGrid 
    runat="server"
    ID="_customerTable"
    CssClass="gridDisplay"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerRow"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Last Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Address 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address1") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Address 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address2") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

The problem is, I need to set up a cssclass for cells that meet certain criteria in a column.  The best I can seem to figure out is a rather ugly method--either specifically doing e.Item.Cells[0]...[3] for each column, or setting ItemStyle-CssClass="firstName"..."address2", and then updating the cssclass for a cell based on my conditions and whether or not the cell's cssclass matches.

This seems like a really ugly solution, though, so I'd far prefer any advice on a better way--if one exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your criteria is, but if you had something along these lines:

```
<asp:DataGrid
    ...
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID='lbl' 
                     Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %>' 
                     CssClass= "%conditional_expression%"   />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>                
    ...
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Assuming you had css classes txtBlue and txtPink, and the criteria is based of a Gender column, then the conditional_expression might be something like:

```
<% DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Gender") == "Male" ? "txtBlue" : "txtPink" %>
```

Not sure the above is valid syntax, just a suggestion.

Comment: That works for text styles, but for styles like background, outline, cursor, vertical-align, etc., you really want the style on the table cell itself, not a span inside the cell.

Comment: Oops, I meant border, not outline.  :)